# How to create a singleton class based on its input?

Tags: python

I have a class defined as

```
class Conditional_Singleton(object):
    def __init__(self, condition=None):
        self.initialization = some_func_of(condition)
```

Since the "initialization" step really takes a lot of time to run and the output could be huge, I would really like that the class not be recreated over and over again given the same input, but do so once the input changes. Any ideas?

Comment: What does your "condition" look like?

Comment: condition is actually another class that is a singleton object but will be changed millions of times during runtime. Why I want this Conditional_Singleton to be conditional is simply because each singleton "contidion" will be fed into "Conditional_Singleton" several times during its short lifetime, when it would be better to keep the "Conditional_Singleton" unchanged. I realize this question has been raised before, but presumably setting up a pool isn't a solution here.

Comment: Why do you need a singleton at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Conditional_Singleton(object):
    saved_insances = {}
    def __new__(cls, condition = None):
        if not condition in cls.saved_instances:
            cls.saved_instances[condition] = super(
                Conditional_Singleton, cls).__new__(cls)
        return cls.saved_instances[condition]
    def __init__(self, condition = None):
        if not hasattr(self, 'initialization'):
            self.initialization = some_func_of(condition)
```

This will save the dict of created instances in the class itself and automatically reuse them if the same condition is passed.

Edit: Just saw your comment. You need to find a good way to hash `condition` for this to work, so unless it derives from a class that implements `__hash__`, you need to implement it yourself.

Edit 2: Using `__new__` instead of `__init__` for the singleton.

Comment: Thanks. The thoughts have converged to making a hashable input, or I guess I need to restructure the code so that the expensive computation become a property of the input class, somethine like that.

Comment: Why `__init__` and not `__new__`? Then the actual class instances could be saved, not their `__dict__`.

Comment: Wow, I just typed it out instead of copy / pasting and totally forgot about this. I'll edit. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: You mean `if not hasattr(self, 'initialization'):`  do you? getattr would result in an error at least in Python3

Comment: @M.Beining I think I meant `getattr(self, 'blah', None)` but I've updated it to use `hasattr` -- thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially do something like this:

```
myInstances = {}

myInstances['condition'] = Conditional_Singleton('condition')
```

In other parts of your code you'd do something like this:

```
if 'condition' in myInstances:
  # something down here that works with that instance
```

Whether or not that fits with your requirement is going to depend on whether or not you can simplify conditions to be something hashable for use as a dictionary key.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Code reconstruction is then needed to avoid those nuisances.